# Performing a PUT update in dojo using GitHub api returns 400: problems parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, github, dojo, github-api

Basically I am trying to update a file on Github using the api. When I do this in Poster it works no problem and I get a response from the server. When sending the exact same params in an xhr put request however, I receive a 400: Bad request error - Problems parsing JSON. Heres my request:

```
             var contentArgs = {
                  "message": "Auto TODO commit updating technical debt",
              "committer": {
                "name": "TODO",
                "email": "tododebttracker@gmail.com"
              },
              "content": "bXkgdXBkYXRlZCBmaWxlIGNvbnRlbnRz",
              "sha": "fb617c9e42866ca2446545e0c2725048f6f9530c"
            };
            xhr.put({
            // The URL to request
                url : url,
                headers : {"Authorization" : "token 289543b6aca2454165451a1afcf115fa9a97"},
                content : contentArgs,
                handleAs : "json",
                load : lang.hitch(this,function(result) {
                    deferred.resolve({"hasError" : false,
                           "response": result});
                }),
                error : lang.hitch(this,function(result) {
                    deferred.resolve({"hasError" : true,
                       "response": result });
                })
            });
```

I've tried every possible variation of the contentArgs JSON and I have also tried using JSON.stringify on the contentArgs but having no joy. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming you're using `dojo/_base/xhr` (there is a new `dojo/request/xhr` module as well now, and `dojo/_base/xhr` is deprecated).

There is one problem here, the `content` parameter should only be used for query parameters, if I recall correctly. I can't say for sure, because that module is probably one of the worst documented modules of all.

The documentation says you should probably use the `data` property in stead of `content` but I tried that and it didn't fix it either.

However, after using the `postData` property with `JSON.stringify(contentArgs);` it does seem to work. So, try this:

```js
xhr.put({
    // The URL to request
    url : url,
    headers : {"Authorization" : "token 289543b6aca2454165451a1afcf115fa9a97", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    postData : JSON.stringify(contentArgs),
    handleAs : "json",
    load : function() {},
    error : function() {}
});
```

You should probably also send the header `Content-Type: application/json` to make sure the server knows it's sent as a JSON string.

However, if you're using Dojo 1.8+, I would recommend using **dojo/request/xhr**. It has a similar API, but it looks a bit cleaner (and is better documented as well):

```js
xhr.put(url, {
    headers : {"Authorization" : "token 289543b6aca2454165451a1afcf115fa9a97", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data : JSON.stringify(contentArgs),
    handleAs : "json"
});
```

Here's an example using both: http://jsfiddle.net/rvnkro8h/ I removed some stuff and used a different URL, but this should proberly send the request payload as JSON.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks for your help! I didn't realise dojo/request/xhr was a more updated module, I'll definitely use that from now on.